# How to formally write a sign sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, definition

Is it correct way to write [sign sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_sequence):

$\{a_i\}_{i=1}^N|a_i \in \{+1, -1\}$

?

I try writing the following: "Finite sequence of N elements when each element is +1 or -1". Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours seems to be fine. Alternative is to regard the sequence as a function
$$a:\mathbb{N} \to \{-1,1\}.$$ That is, $a_n$ is a function that takes as an argument a natural number $n$ and indicates if this term is $-1$ or $1$.